# Mysql group by two columns with where condition and maximum date of third column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max, aggregate-functions

I have a table that has user_id, item_id and last_date as columns. This last columns type is in *datetime*.

I need to retrieve the *last_date* by grouping columns *user_id* & *item_id* with condition where *type_id* is like **foo** and very import I need to have all columns in the result because in mytable there are more columns.

Here is mytable structure :

```
user_id  item_id      last_date         type_id
129678      2     2019-02-17 11:00:09     foo
129678      1     2019-02-17 11:00:15     foo
129678      2     2019-02-17 11:00:10     bar
129678      2     2019-02-17 11:00:10     bar
129678      2     2019-02-17 11:00:11     foo
129678      2     2019-02-17 11:00:15     foo
129678      1     2019-02-17 11:00:09     foo
129678      2     2019-02-17 11:00:14     bar
129678      2     2019-02-17 11:00:08     bar
129678      2     2019-02-17 11:00:11     foo
129678      2     2019-02-17 11:00:14     bar
129678      2     2019-02-17 11:00:10     foo
12a0d8      3     2019-02-17 11:00:08     foo
12a0d8      2     2019-02-17 11:00:12     foo
12a0d8      3     2019-02-17 11:00:08     bar
12a0d8      3     2019-02-17 11:00:12     bar
12a0d8      1     2019-02-17 11:00:10     foo
12a0d8      1     2019-02-17 11:00:11     bar
12a0d8      3     2019-02-17 11:00:14     foo
12a0d8      3     2019-02-17 11:00:12     foo
18ae98      2     2019-02-17 11:00:12     foo
18ae98      3     2019-02-17 11:00:07     bar
18ae98      1     2019-02-17 11:00:13     bar
18ae98      1     2019-02-17 11:00:14     foo
18ae98      2     2019-02-17 11:00:09     foo
18ae98      2     2019-02-17 11:00:13     foo
18ae98      3     2019-02-17 11:00:08     foo
18ae98      1     2019-02-17 11:00:12     foo
18ae98      3     2019-02-17 11:00:10     foo
18ae98      1     2019-02-17 11:00:12     foo
```

Here is the query that i tried for this purpose :

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
  WHERE last_date IN (
    SELECT MAX(last_date)
    FROM mytable
    WHERE type_id LIKE 'foo'
    GROUP BY user_id, item_id
  )
```

Desired result :

```
user_id  item_id      last_date         type_id
129678      1     2019-02-17 11:00:15     foo
129678      2     2019-02-17 11:00:15     foo
12a0d8      1     2019-02-17 11:00:10     foo
12a0d8      2     2019-02-17 11:00:12     foo
12a0d8      3     2019-02-17 11:00:14     foo
18ae98      1     2019-02-17 11:00:14     foo
18ae98      2     2019-02-17 11:00:13     foo
18ae98      3     2019-02-17 11:00:10     foo
```

But the result is weird !! For example, that return for *user_id* multiple *item_id* with same value...

**Edit :**

If I use this query that seams to work well but I must specify an interval date.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE type_id LIKE 'foo'
AND last_date > date_sub(curdate(), interval 2 day)
GROUP BY user_id, item_id
```

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: Specify the expected result as well, having the table data as above.

Comment: @jarlh I'm using two version : v5.1.47 (dev), v5.7.19 (prod). For the desired result I updated my question.

Comment: I have edit my question with temporary solution.

Answer (score 1):

Below would be one way -

```
    SELECT 
from       MyTable t1 
INNER JOIN 
           ( 
                    SELECT   user_id, 
                             item_id, 
                             max(last_date) AS lastdate 
                    FROM     MyTable 
                    WHERE    type_id='foo' 
                    GROUP BY user_id, 
                             item_id) t2 
ON         t1.user_id=t2.user_id 
AND        t1.item_id=t2.item_id 
AND        t1.last_date=t2.lastdate
```

Comment: well if I use your query that seams to work good (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7c5c2/1) but in my DB with phpMyAdmin there still double/triple same values for *item_id* :\

Comment: Can you sample data for which you are getting unexpected output. Query will return duplicates only if if you more entries for particular - *user_id, item_id, last_date*

Answer (score 0):

use corelated subquery

```
   SELECT t1.* FROM mytable t1
   WHERE last_date = (
    SELECT MAX(last_date)
    FROM mytable t2
    WHERE t1.user_id=t2.user_id and t1.itemid=t2.itemid    
    and type_id LIKE 'foo'

  )
```

Comment: Now fix that double `WHERE`!

Comment: well if I use your query that seams to work good (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7c5c2/3) but in my DB with phpMyAdmin there still double/triple same values for *item_id* :\ and I have to add second condition "t2.type_id LIKE 'foo'"

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin : nope sorry, I have edit my question with temporary solution.

Comment: i think your data in fiddle and server is not same otherwise there is no way to work it on fiddle but not in your server

Comment: the problem is I can't share data with you because it's private :\ sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can simply group on the 2 columns you are focussing on and then grab the max(last_date). The subquery you were using previously would not limit on the max(last_date) as multiple user_id and item_id combinations can apply to the same date.

Below is a write up with your sample data that produces the expected result without having to write an extra nested query.

```
declare @t table (
user_id nvarchar(15),
item_id int,
last_date datetime2,
type_id nvarchar(3)
);

insert into  @t (user_id, item_id, last_date, type_id)
values
('129678',      2,     '2019-02-17 11:00:09',     'foo'),
('129678',      1,     '2019-02-17 11:00:15',     'foo'),
('129678',      2,     '2019-02-17 11:00:10',     'bar'),
('129678',      2,     '2019-02-17 11:00:10',     'bar'),
('129678',      2,     '2019-02-17 11:00:11',     'foo'),
('129678',      2,     '2019-02-17 11:00:15',     'foo'),
('129678',      1,     '2019-02-17 11:00:09',     'foo'),
('129678',      2,     '2019-02-17 11:00:14',     'bar'),
('129678',      2,     '2019-02-17 11:00:08',     'bar'),
('129678',      2,     '2019-02-17 11:00:11',     'foo'),
('129678',      2,     '2019-02-17 11:00:14',     'bar'),
('129678',      2,     '2019-02-17 11:00:10',     'foo'),
('12a0d8',      3,     '2019-02-17 11:00:08',     'foo'),
('12a0d8',      2,     '2019-02-17 11:00:12',     'foo'),
('12a0d8',      3,     '2019-02-17 11:00:08',     'bar'),
('12a0d8',      3,     '2019-02-17 11:00:12',     'bar'),
('12a0d8',      1,     '2019-02-17 11:00:10',     'foo'),
('12a0d8',      1,     '2019-02-17 11:00:11',     'bar'),
('12a0d8',      3,     '2019-02-17 11:00:14',     'foo'),
('12a0d8',      3,     '2019-02-17 11:00:12',     'foo'),
('18ae98',      2,     '2019-02-17 11:00:12',     'foo'),
('18ae98',      3,     '2019-02-17 11:00:07',     'bar'),
('18ae98',      1,     '2019-02-17 11:00:13',     'bar'),
('18ae98',      1,     '2019-02-17 11:00:14',     'foo'),
('18ae98',      2,     '2019-02-17 11:00:09',     'foo'),
('18ae98',      2,     '2019-02-17 11:00:13',     'foo'),
('18ae98',      3,     '2019-02-17 11:00:08',     'foo'),
('18ae98',      1,     '2019-02-17 11:00:12',     'foo'),
('18ae98',      3,     '2019-02-17 11:00:10',     'foo'),
('18ae98',      1,     '2019-02-17 11:00:12',     'foo');

select * from (
select USER_ID, item_id, MAX(last_date) as last_date, type_id 
from @t where type_id = 'foo' group by user_id, item_id, type_id
) x
order by user_id, item_id;
```

Comment: thx for your reply but 'group by' is not in the right place (syntax)

Comment: @Peacefull thank you for pointing that out (serves me right for not pasting straight from my query window). I have moved the where clause. The query does provide the intended result when run (with the where clause in the right place obviously).

Comment: No problem, your query is better now but in my first request I need to return all columns with an SELECT *  If I use a SELECT with some columns that works good. Here is my problem...

Comment: I have added a select * as an outer query. I'm not sure why select * would be preferable to selecting the columns individually. However the query posted gives the intended result using under the proposed conditions.

Comment: I tried your last change but it steal returning only select columns and not all other from my DB.

Comment: What would you like to see from the other columns? Because the data is aggregated by date you lose multiple dates. Are there other columns that vary per LastDate that you want to see? Could you let me know what your expected output is? Column names, nulls etc.